# Proof of inequality for complex numbers

Tags: linear-algebra

I have been working on this proof and seem to be going in circles. I assume I need to use the triangle inequality but every time I do so I seem to end up where I started. I am trying to prove
$$|z+1|\le|z+1|^2+|z| \qquad, \forall z\in\mathbb C$$
Any tips on how to approach this would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen $z$ is given to be complex, how can it be positive and negative?

Comment: Use polar coordinates, than it is easy to show that the squared module is greater than the simple module thanks to the added $1$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Break this up into two cases.  If $|z+1| \geq 1$, then we have
$$
|z+1| \leq |z+1|^2 \leq |z+1|^2 + |z|
$$
If $|z+1| \leq 1$, we then have
$$
|z| = |z+1 - 1| \geq 1 - |z+1| \geq |z+1| \cdot (1 - |z+1|) =  |z+1| - |z+1|^2
$$
which is to say that 
$$
|z+1| \leq |z| + |z+1|^2
$$
as desired.

Comment: It was the breaking it into cases that was the part I was missing, thank you so much!

Comment: @Eric no problem; it took me a while to think of what to do in the second case.